# Extrapolation of pixels position

Tags: graphics, interpolation, curve

I have an image with some curve draw in it and I want to extrapolate positions of next few pixels based on already drawn ones. An example is shown in figure 1. For this situation it is easy to fit curve (some parabola) using the least square fit (figure 2) and then based on this fit rasterize the curve to find next pixels (I also need the vector curve for some further calculations).

The problem is that there is often situations like one shown in figure 3, where I can't use curves like parabola, because I can't define such function. Have you any idea how to extrapolate curve/pixels which will work in both cases?

[image: fitting curves through drawn pixels]

Comment: I hope this is helpful to you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equations -- though I do not know any mechanism for fitting parametric equations to given points, I hope that is just my ignorance.

Comment: Thank you, I think that parametric equations will work.